# Reasons for high disk time but minimal IOPS

Tags: hard-drive, iops

Can anyone possibly suggest scenarios on a large database system where system stats show a rapidly increasing disk time stats, but next to no actual disk IO? When working with lots of large files, what could be happening?

Comment: High CPU, memory pressure?

Comment: Chopper3's comment is germane. What's CPU and memory load look like? Are we possibly seeing a really long disk access queue? And what is the layout of your disks - single disk? JBOD? RAID and what level? We're kind of in the dark here.

Comment: even a single request could lead on a hdd on request times into seconds. this is due to the nature of how the device works.